# Batch read txt then split line for line and write out in other txt

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem with batch. I need to read one `.txt` with this lines:

```
cod_est nro_prsna_clnte          cod_prdto                cod_sub_prdto            cod_cntto                fch_est                
------- ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ -----------------------
C         777388304                       93                     2003             690005635940 2016-10-19 00:00:00.000

C         777388304                       93                     2003             690005635930 2016-10-18 00:00:00.000
```

there are many spaces between words
I can read de txt but a can't split line for line and the result leave like this

```
C,777388304,93,2003,690005635940,2016-10-19
C,777388304,93,2003,690005635930,2016-10-18
```

This my code:

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%i in (OFB_INF_PSN.txt) do (
    set t=
    for %%x in (%%i) do (
        echo %%x >> OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F "tokens=1-6" %%i in (OFB_INF_PSN.txt) do echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n>> OFB_INF_PSN_2.txt
```

(see `for /? |more` from the prompt for documentation.

token=1-6 means make 6 tokens, %%i to %%n

By default, the delimiter is <kbd>space</kbd> (also `,` and `;`)